# constructor property of a prototype object

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor, prototypal-inheritance

Consider the following snippet:

```
function Dog(){this.tail = true;}
var benji = new Dog();
var rusty = new Dog();
Dog.prototype.say = function(){return 'Woof!';}
alert(benji.say()); // this alerts woof!
alert(rusty.say()); // this alerts woof!
alert(benji.constructor.prototype.constructor); // THIS ALERTS THE DOG FUNCTION
alert(typeof benji.constructor.prototype.tail) // THIS ALERTS UNDEFINED
```

Why does the `benji.constructor.prototype.constructor` `alert` the dog function?
Shouldn't it be an `Object()` constructor?

Comment: `benji.constructor == Dog` only because `Dog.prototype.constructor = Dog`

Comment: tail is an instance specific member and say is a prototype (shared) member, more on prototype and constructor functions here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple:

```
+-----------------+       tail
|                 |-----------------> [true]
|      benji      |
|                 |
+-----------------+
         |
         | __proto__
         |
         v
+-----------------+    constructor    +-----------------+
|                 |------------------>|                 |
|  Dog.prototype  |                   |       Dog       |
|                 |<------------------|                 |
+-----------------+     prototype     +-----------------+
         |
         | __proto__
         |
         v
+-----------------+    constructor    +-----------------+
|                 |------------------>|                 |
| Object.prototype|                   |      Object     |
|                 |<------------------|                 |
+-----------------+     prototype     +-----------------+
```

1. `benji.constructor` is `Dog`.
2. `benji.constructor.prototype` is `Dog.prototype`.
3. `benji.constructor.prototype.constructor` is `Dog`.
4. `benji.constructor.prototype.constructor.prototype` is `Dog.prototype`.
5. `benji.constructor.prototype.constructor.prototype.constructor` is `Dog`.

This goes on forever. Instead what you want is `Object.getPrototypeOf`:

1. `Object.getPrototypeOf(benji).constructor` is `Dog`.
2. `Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(benji)).constructor` is `Object`.

Since `Object.getPrototypeOf` is iterated you could create a special function for it:

```
function getPrototypeOf(n, object) {
    if (n === 0) return object;
    else return getPrototypeOf(n - 1, Object.getPrototypeOf(object));
}
```

Now you can use it as follows:

```
getPrototypeOf(1, benji).constructor; // Dog
getPrototypeOf(2, benji).constructor; // Object
```

That's all folks.

Comment: Helps a lot ! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`benji.constructor` resolves to `Dog`. Note that `benji` doesn't actually have it's own `constructor` property: it inherits the `constructor` property from its prototype. `benji.constructor` really is `Dog.prototype.constructor`, just like `benji.say` is really `Dog.prototype.say`.

Thus, `benji.constructor.prototype` is actually `Dog.prototype`, which is the prototype where `benji` inherits prototypal properties from.

Finally, therefore, `benji.constructor.prototype.constructor` is really `Dog.prototype.constructor`, which is the same as `benji.constructor`.

By contrast, `benji` *does* have his own `tail` property. That is set directly on the instance when it is constructed, and it is not inherited from the prototype.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the prototype of `Dog` doesn't contain the property. Instead, you are setting it for every new instance, inside the constructor function. To have `tail` in the prototype, you'd have to define it there:

```
Dog.prototype.tail = true;
```